# Replace character in multiple columns of panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I create by reading a XLSX file and I need to replace a lot of dot by commas because I don't know why in Excel it shows a comma but in panda dataframe it is a dot instead for decimal separator. I have 29 columns to replace dot by commas, so I figured out it would be better to use a list to store all my columns name and a for loop to iterate though all the column where I want to replace those dots by commas.

But unfortunately I got error when I tried the following code :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

root = tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, bg='lightsteelblue2', relief='raised')
canvas1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='File Conversion Tool', bg='lightsteelblue2')
label1.config(font=('helvetica', 20))
canvas1.create_window(150, 60, window=label1)

read_file = pd.DataFrame()


def get_excel_onefolder():
    global read_file
    import_dir_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    file_ext = "*.xlsx"
    list_xlsx_file = list(pathlib.Path(import_dir_path).glob(file_ext))
    lst_rpl = ['col24', 'col25', 'col26', 'col45', 'col46', 'col47', 'col69', 'col75', 'col76', 'col77', 'col105', 'col106',
               'col107', 'col108', 'col109', 'col110', 'col111', 'col112', 'col254', 'col255', 'col256', 'col257', 'col258',
               'col259', 'col260', 'col261', 'col262', 'col352', 'col353']
    len_lst = len(lst_rpl)
    for xlsx_file_path in list_xlsx_file:
        read_file = pd.read_excel(xlsx_file_path)
        read_file['Time'] = read_file['Time'].str.replace(',', '.')
        for i in range(len_lst):
            read_file[lst_rpl[i]] = read_file[lst_rpl[i]].str.replace('.', ',')
        output_path = str(xlsx_file_path) + ".csv"
        read_file.to_csv(output_path, index=None, header=True, decimal=',', sep=';')
    tk.messagebox.showinfo(title="Import success", message="CSV file import successful !")


XLSX_to_CSV = tk.Button(text="Import Excel File & Convert to CSV", command=get_excel_onefolder, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(150, 180, window=XLSX_to_CSV)

root.mainloop()
```

The error I got is KeyError: 'col24'

Edit :
I fixed my problem by adding argument for NaN value, na_values to .read_excel with decimal=',' and it works fine now

```
read_file = pd.read_excel(xlsx_file_path, decimal=',', na_values=['#NV', ' '])
```

My problem was because I had column which was not recognized as float because of NaN value.

The working function is now :

```
def get_excel_onefolder():
    global read_file
    import_dir_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    file_ext = "*.xlsx"
    list_xlsx_file = list(pathlib.Path(import_dir_path).glob(file_ext))
    for xlsx_file_path in list_xlsx_file:
        read_file = pd.read_excel(xlsx_file_path, decimal=',', na_values=['#NV', ' '])
        read_file['Time'] = read_file['Time'].str.replace(',', '.')
        path_without_ext = os.path.splitext(str(xlsx_file_path))[0]
        output_path = path_without_ext + ".csv"
        read_file.to_csv(output_path, index=None, header=True, decimal=',', sep=';')
    tk.messagebox.showinfo(title="Import success", message="CSV file import successful !")
```

Answer (score 0):

pandas tries to autoformat commas into dots.  You can change this behavior with the `decimal` parameter:

`read_file = pd.read_excel(xlsx_file_path)` -> `read_file = pd.read_excel(xlsx_file_path, decimal=",")`

Comment: I solved my problem by modifying the line read_excel and adding na_values argument read_file = pd.read_excel(xlsx_file_path, decimal=',', na_values=['#NV', ' '])

Answer (score 0):

```
    for x in list_col:
       df[list_col] = df[list_col].apply(lamba x: str(x).replace('.' , ',') if '.' in str(x) else x)
```

Don't know whether this code might be helpful to you or not. This snippet helps you to replace dots as commas in all the columns if a dot is present.